# How to make an async call and function definition using CodeDom?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, implementation, codedom

I've recently started working with CodeDom to generate classes and interfaces, but never to define functions or create and start a `Task`. I need to replicate this code using CodeDom:

```
public async Task<CustomTestResponse> CustomObjectTestAsync(CustomObjectTestRequest request)
{
    var call = await Task.Run<CustomObjectTestResponse>(() =>
    {
        CustomObjectTestResponse response = new CustomObjectTestResponse();
        string result;
        TESTING.Testing test;

        response.CustomObjectTestResponseResult = BaseChannel.CustomObjectTest(request.Test, request.IsFake, out result, out test);
        response.OutTest = test;
        response.Result = result;

        return response;
    });

    return call;
}
```

i have the function definition done, but i can't figure out how to do the inside part (from the `var call` to the `return call;`) Here is what i have:

```
CodeMemberMethod implementationMethod = new CodeMemberMethod();
implementationMethod.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
implementationMethod.Name = asyncMethod.Identifier.ToString() + "Async";
implementationMethod.ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference("async Task<" + className + "Response>");
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I've slowly started progressing, but by using one big `CodeSnippetExpression` and generating my desired code and shoving inside that variable... surely there must be a better way!